# Is there a maximum factor by which difficulty can change?

Tags: protocol, difficulty

I seem to recall, long ago, being told that difficulty couldn't change more than a certain amount at each retarget, but I can't seem to find what that factor is (or even confirmation that such a factor exists) no matter how hard I google. Does such a factor exist and if so what is its value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difficulty never changes by more than a factor of 4 (except for in a special case that only applies on testnet).

The code that enforces this is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/d62a1947be5350ed60066ccacc7aba43bbdf48fb/src/main.cpp#L875).

Answer (score 8):

Well doesn't that figure, the moment I ask the question my google-fu kicks in.

[This wiki article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target) states:

> A single retarget never changes the target by more than a factor of 4
>   either way to prevent large changes in difficulty.

Comment: Ah, gotta love moments like this! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I seriously think there's something about the act of phrasing a question for SE that activates some hidden bit of gray matter and creates superior search terms. It's not so annoying when it's an hour later, this one was mere seconds :P

Comment: Well, it's still a good question and a good answer.

Comment: Interesting that the article would consider a change from the currently difficult of 1,726,567 to either 5,000,000 or 500,000 as not being a large change... I guess it's considering it from a logarithmic perspective?